# Реализация интерфейса в производном классе

Tags: java, интерфейс

Класс `А` реализует интерфейсы `Serializable` и `Cloneable`. От него наследуется класс `B`.

Реализует ли производный класс интерфейсы базового класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализует. В этом можно убедиться на примере:

```
public class A implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable { }

public class B extends A { }

B b = new B();
System.out.println(b instanceof java.io.Serializable);
System.out.println(b instanceof Cloneable);
```

В обоих случаях будет выведено `true`.

---

По поводу комментария:

Если класс `A` будет абстрактным:

```
public abstract class A implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable { }
```

то в данном конкретном случае для класса `B` ничего не поменяется.

Однако если, например, класс `A` будет выглядеть так:

```
public abstract class A implements AutoCloseable { }
```

то в классе `public class B extends A` придётся реализовать метод `close` из интерфейса `AutoCloseable`, потому что иначе возникнет ошибка компиляции:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - B is not abstract and does not override abstract method close() in java.lang.AutoCloseable

Comment: А если в качестве базового класса выступает абстрактный класс - это же ничего не меняет?

Comment: @studentST в плане наследования не меняет. Во втором примере у меня как раз представлен абстрактный класс `A`.